# SQL Server: Adding sequence number to rows with same key field, per key value

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database with a table that has a field that contains the same value for multiple rows.  I want to add a sequence number for the rows with the same value in the field.  For example if my data is like;

```
Field1
A
A
B
B
B
```

I want sequence numbers for each row like;

```
Field1     SequenceNumber
A              1
A              2
B              1
B              2
B              3
```

Comment: Why? Currently,  this is arbitrary.  Data has meaning, value, and aside from making a table with letters and numbers,  the data has no value here.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in another topic

```
select Field1
Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Field1 order by Field1) as SequenceNumber
from mytable
order by Field1, SequenceNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new table, if not, without a primary key or unique index you cannot update your table.

```
create table new_table
(
    id int,
    field1 char(1)
);

with seqnum as
(
    select field1, row_number() over (partition by field1) id
    from your_table
)
insert into new_table (id, field1)
values (seqnum.id, seqnum.field1;
```

Now you can create a primary key on (id, field1)

Or delete the old_table and rename new_table using the old name.

If your actual table has a unique index, then you can use it to update it.

Comment: Unfortunately,  this is arbitrary. Is that really all the OP wanted to know?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have an automatic resetting sequence number per group, fully and natively enforced by the server. It can only natively enforce constraints on a single-row basis, or on an entire table.

There are steps you can take with fairly complicated triggers, but then you run into issues with concurrency. My suggestion is to instead simply put a date column on each row. At the time of querying or application use, you can simply group by the `Field` and then order by the date column. This will achieve the exact same thing (placing the rows in a particular, countable, ordinally-assignable position).